# Is there any book that consists of notations from various composers and suits my skill level?

Tags: violin

I am an intermediate violinist pursuing grade 4 from ABRSM. I am interested in playing classical music. Is there any book that consists of notations from various composers and suits my skill level? If yes, can you please let me know the name and publication?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that old exam books are (certainly were) available from ABRSM. All the grade 4 pieces will be of similar playing standard - they change every 2 years. If the pieces themselves are not still available, there will be a list of earlier ones from AB. Try Trinity as well.

Comment: I follow this approach, great fun. Each ABRSM exam list contains three pieces for each of three sections from which you choose one for the exam. But if you are just looking for pieces all 9 will be suitable. They also list another 9 not included in the book which you could look for separately.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, but someone else's opinion of the difficulty of a piece (especially an advanced musician of many decades) may not be as helpful as you think. As a teacher my biggest challenge has been selecting pieces of the right level, and I'm sorry to say that I don't get it right as often as I would like.

Check out this link, consisting of a list of graded violin studies. I am not terribly familiar with the violin repertoire, but based on what I know of the composers and recognizing some of the works on this list, it looks about right to me:

http://www.violinmasterclass.com/en/graded-repertoire/violin-methods-and-etudes

Keep in mind that many (or most) of these works may be available completely for free: http://imslp.org/

You can put them on Kindle or iPad. Or, if you prefer paper, you can print them out and add them to your own book of repertoire.

Hope this helps! Good luck.